# Seaborn jointplot custom bandwidth

Tags: python, r, seaborn, kernel-density

I'm trying to use Seaborn's jointplot function to create a 2D kernel density estimation. I have used R in the past using the 'ks' package to calculate the plug-in bandwidth and calculate the KDE as follows (I don't want to use the "rule-of-thumb" methods):

```
library(ks)
data(unicef)
x_vals <- unicef[sample(nrow(unicef), 10), 1]
y_vals <- unicef[sample(nrow(unicef), 10), 1]
mydf <- data.frame(x_vals, y_vals)
H <- Hpi(mydf)
fhat <- kde(x=mydf, H=H)
plot(fhat)
```

The above snippet returns a 2 x 2 matrix for the bandwidth H.

I am wanting to use the same bandwidth calculation in Seaborn's jointplot function. Two questions: i) is there a Python-centric method for calculating the bandwidth like the R way above?; ii) once I have the bandwidth, how do I pass it to joinpoint, as it accepts a list of values, not a matrix?

Thanks

Comment: could you make this a runable example?

Comment: you can configure the KDE through the `joint_kws` argument. That dictionary is passed directly to the function that draw the joint distirbution. In this case, that function is: http://web.stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.kdeplot.html#seaborn.kdeplot

Comment: @PaulH edited the question to make it a more full example.

Comment: I'm currently working through the process of estimating bandwidth using either the plugin estimator or a multivariate least squares cross validation method.  I have not found an implementation in python of the plugin estimator but there is an lscv implementation in statsmodels: http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/generated/statsmodels.nonparametric.kernel_density.KDEMultivariate.html